# Proper way of using insert into value select

Tags: php

I am having with my query because Insert into value and select is not working, Is this the proper way of using it? thankyou!

This is my query line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `stud_class` (`stud_fullname`, `stud_uid`,`stud_code`, `stud_subject`, `stud_cname`,`stat`)  VALUES ('$stud_full','$stud_uid',(SELECT subject_code,subsubject,class_Name FROM subject WHERE subject_code = '$subcode'),1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery that's used as an expression is only allowed to return one value, not multiple columns.

You need to use the `SELECT` query as the source of all the values, not as an expression inside the `VALUES` list.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `stud_class` (`stud_fullname`, `stud_uid`,`stud_code`, `stud_subject`, `stud_cname`,`stat`)  
    SELECT '$stud_full','$stud_uid', subject_code,subsubject,class_Name, 1
    FROM subject WHERE subject_code = '$subcode')";
```

You should also use a prepared statement rather than substituting variables into the SQL string. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)